# grails <meta name="layout" ... w3c html5 [invalid] Markup validation

Tags: validation, grails, w3c, meta

When I check the html 5 Markup Validation Service I don't want to get these errors anymore:

```
Error Line 159, Column 51: Attribute name not allowed on element meta at this point.

            <meta name="layout" content="main_profil"/>

Error Line 159, Column 51: Element meta is missing required attribute itemprop.

            <meta name="layout" content="main_profil"/>
```

Is there anyway to solve this? I need this meta tag on top of the gsp to say which Layout will be used.

Comment: You are missing itemprop attribute for meta tag

Comment: Also thought so, but when i give it for example the itemprop="information" it says

Comment: Error Line 159, Column 74: The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.

    <meta name="layout" content="main_arztprofil" itemprop="information"/>

Comment: Have you tried to analyze a popular website? or any website, for that matter. It is extremely difficult to comply with all the HTML5 specs (not to mention the CSS3). And in my humble opinion, that is not a significant error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages you are getting indicate that you have the `<meta>` element in the `<body>` section of your page, when it should be in the `<head>` section.

However, "layout" is not a valid name for the `<meta>` element in HTML5, so you're not going to be able to stop the validator from reporting an error for that.

You could try registering the "layout" name on the [WHATWG wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) but it will take some time for the validator to catch up with that.

Comment: ah okay, i also dont think that its an significant error, but it would be awesome to see a bright green light from w3c, just for aesthetic reasons :D  ... funny thing is that even www.grails.org  gets an error Error on markup validation for that meta tag... haha

Comment: @johnSmith, the procedure of registering `meta` names is described in the WHATWG wiki cited. So you can do that, if you care about the green light so much. Allow a few months for delivery.

Comment: about 2 months ago i did so, nothing happend i didn´t even got an email